# Error with using esttex on regression function

Tags: r, regression

After running `esttex` I get the error `"Error in etable(..., vcov = vcov, stage = stage, agg = agg, se = se, ssc = ssc,  :  The second element of '...' (named '') is not valid: it should be a fixest object or a list of fixest objects, it is neither."`

This is the regression function and my use of `esttex`:
`commuting_grav_reg = gravity_regression_flows(commute, T, 50)`

```
esttex(commuting_grav_reg, digits = 5, drop(c("","statistic", "p.value")), file = "../output/commuting_grav_reg")
```

The regression that is called from the function "gravity_regression_flows" is:

```
gravity_regression_flows <- function(flow_df, include_distance, n_iter) {
different_state <- function(origin, destination) {
if_else(str_sub(origin, end = 2) == str_sub(destination, end = 2), 0, 1)
 }
  flow_df <- flow_df %>% 
   mutate(border = different_state(origin, destination))
  
   if (include_distance) {
     grav_reg <- fepois(flow ~ border + log(dist) | origin + destination,
                       flow_df, glm.iter = n_iter)
   } else {
     grav_reg <- fepois(flow ~ border | origin + destination,
                       flow_df, glm.iter = n_iter)
   }
  grav_reg
}
```